# Update datagrid using data binding from database using observable object

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I’m trying to use data binding as close to MVVM as possible to update a WPF datagrid with data from a database. I think I’m still struggling with the concept, to which I haven’t found (or understood) the answer in any examples I’ve been through. There is a lot of information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020519/how-to-update-datagrid-using-mvvm-databinding) post, but unless I've missed something, my specific question below is not addressed.

Question:
How to trigger  PropertyChangedEventArgs when another class updates the SQL database?

I’ve tried something as follows, however, it doesn’t work (presumably because I’m notifying in a new instance). If I reopen the window that the XAML I can see that the additional entries have been added to the database, it’s just not updating automatically.

**TableView.xaml.cs**

```
private void AddNode()
{
    SQL.InsertNode(); //this fires a method to add a row to the database
    ViewModel viewmodel = new ViewModel(); //this fires the messagebox in my viewmodel the the notification is raised
    viewmodel.FillList(); // this doesn't seem to do anything. Cluthing at straws really
}
```

Hopefully I’m on the right track. To help answer the question, I’ve provided everything I think you would need below.

Here is my **XAML - TableView.xaml**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" 
          x:Name="NodeTableDataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan ="3" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Add Row" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path='id'}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Node Name" Binding="{Binding Path='NodeName', Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Easting (m)" Binding="{Binding Path='x'}" IsReadOnly="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Northing (m)" Binding="{Binding Path='y'}" IsReadOnly="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cover Level (m)" Binding="{Binding Path='z_cover'}" IsReadOnly="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the **code behind - TableView.xaml.cs**

```
public TableView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    co = new ViewModel();
    base.DataContext = co;
}
```

And my **View Model**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SQLiteCommand command;
    SQLiteDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet ds;

    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _nodes;
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            return this._nodes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_nodes != value)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Table changed");
                OnPropertyChanged("Nodes");
            }

            this._nodes = value;
        }
    }


    public ViewModel()
    {            
        FillList();
    }

    public void FillList()
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM node_table";
            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, SQL.m_dbConnection);
            adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "node_table");

            if (Nodes == null)
                Nodes = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Nodes.Add(new MyModel
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                    NodeName = dr[1].ToString(),
                    x = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString()),
                    y = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3].ToString()),
                    z_cover = Convert.ToInt32(dr[4].ToString())

                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The table view has failed to load from the database with the following error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ds = null;
            adapter.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

**EDIT**  To capture comments "from Juan Carlos Rodriguez"

I have modified the TableView.xaml.cs as follows which does fix the issue for updated SQL calls from the View class so thank you for your response. Very useful.

```
    ViewModel co;

    public TableView()
    {
        SQL.InsertNode();
        InitializeComponent();
        co = new ViewModel();
        base.DataContext = co;
    }

    public void AddNode()
    {
        SQL.InsertNode();
        co.Nodes.Clear();
        co.FillList();
    }
```

I will however, need to be able to update the SQL database from other classes so I am going to have the same problem. I knew this wouldn't work, but this is the bext bit I want to fix.

**Some random class**

```
    public void AddNodeFromRandomClass()
    {
        //Updates the database succesafully, however raises the change in the wrong instance of TableView.
        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.AddNode();
    }
```

Comment: I think this._nodes = value should be executed before OnPropertyChanged("Nodes");

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment you are correct, I've swapped these around but the change still isn't being picked up by the XAML.

Comment: If you're on a different view, and you want to tell that there's an update for the view which contains this collection, you may need to use messenger to notify the view to repopulate, but that's more complex if my understanding to your problem is correct. I could show you that, but I'm using UWP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't never raise the set of `Nodes` because you are not creating a new instance of ObservableCollection, you are adding items to it what doesn't raise the set. An `ObservableCollection` set raises when you change the instance.

```
Nodes.Add( new MyModel()) -> "Doesn't raise the set."

ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModelOC = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>() { "Declare 3 items" };
Nodes = myModelOC -> "This will raise the set".
```

Now that I explained this (I hope I explained myself, if not just let me know) I would like to ask you a few questions. I see this:

```
public TableView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  co = new ViewModel();
  base.DataContext = co;
}
```

This is your xaml.cs ?

Anyway, I would say your problem is that you are setting a `DataContext` and then from another private method you create a new VM, so the VM instance of your `DataContext` and the VM you create in your private are completely different, thats why you aren't getting your `DataGrid` updated, you are updating a VM that isn't set as `DataContext` in the view.

Please edit your post and indicate where you call your `AddNode` and how you show your View so I can tell you how to fix it.

---

First of all this doesn't follow MVVM as you are putting code in your View codebehind:

```
ViewModel co;

public TableView()
{
    SQL.InsertNode();
    InitializeComponent();
    co = new ViewModel();
    base.DataContext = co;
}

public void AddNode()
{
    SQL.InsertNode();
    co.Nodes.Clear();
    co.FillList();
}
```

Before you do your `TableView.Show()` you have to create a ViewModel and set the `TableView` `DataContext`. It would be something like this:

```
ViewModel yourViewModel = new ViewModel();
TableView tableView = new TableView();
tableView.DataContext = yourViewModel;
tableView.Show();
```

And your `TableView.xaml.cs` constructor should be just like this:

```
public TableView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

And your `ViewModel` constructor should be like this:

```
public ViewModel()
{   
    FillList();
    Nodes.Clear();// You could do this if you need it to be cleared
}
```

That being said, for your real problem I suggest you to use events. It really depends on how your architecture is built. I'll give a possible aproach:

Create a new class that will contain your event like this:

```
public static class UpdaterEvent 
{
    public static event EventHandler DataUpdated;

    public static void PublishDataUpdated(EventArgs args) 
    {
        var updaterEvent = DataUpdated;
        if (updaterEvent != null)
            updaterEvent(null, args);
    }
}
```

Now in your ViewModel constructor add this:

```
public ViewModel()
{   
    FillList();
    Nodes.Clear();// You could do this if you need it to be cleared
    UpdaterEvent.DataUpdated += OnDataUpdated;        
}

private void OnDataUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FillList();
}
```

Whenever you need to update your data just do the following:

```
UpdaterEvent.PublishDataUpdated(new EventArgs());
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful response. I've edited the post to include code that now works to update the table from a method called withing the View class based on your answer. 
I'm still unsure however, how to replicate the same function from another class.
Answers to your question, yes it is the xaml.cs but I also want to raise changes from other classes.

Comment: I think my last edit will help you :D sorry for the format but I can't  format it :S

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. Thanks for your determination to resolve my issue.

Comment: This is why we are here :) so glad it helped you